# inequality with expectation of a function

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

**Question**
$X$ is an RV. Let $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a strongly ascending function. $\forall X: m<f(X)$

a. Show that if $f(X)$ has a finite expectation then $P(X\ge t)\le\frac {E[f(X))-m}{f(t)-m}$.

b. Show that if exists $k>0$ such that $e^{kX}$ has a finite expectation then $P(X\ge t)\le\frac {E(e^{kX})}{e^{tk}}$.

**What I did:**

We studied only Markov's and Thebychev's (reqular and one sided) inequalities. I don't really know how to move forward using these inequalities to any of the required expressions...
Thanks

Comment: Hint: $P(X\ge t)\ge P(f(X)-m\ge f(t)-m)$.

Comment: Second hint: let $f(t)=e^{tk}$ and $m=0$, then you get $(b)$

Comment: @Landscape could you please explain why your inequality is true in this direction?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Actually it is an equality: $P(X≥t)=P(f(X)−m≥f(t)−m)$. This is because, since $f$ is **strongly** ascending, $X\ge t\iff f(X)-m\ge f(t)-m$.